# Azure can't find my TFS repositories

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops

I have created a new app service on Azure, that i want to connect to an existing project on my TFS.

The problem is, when i choose Continuous Delivery -> Source and selects Visual Studio Team Service and selects the correct project, it says that there is "No repositories found".

What am i missing?

[image]

And as you can see, there should be a repository:

[image]

Comment: Is your TFS hosted on Azure or on your premises?

Comment: It is just hosted on englund.visualstudio.com

Comment: Have you tried adding a Git repo to your team project? This will let you know if it is permission or only Git is supported.

Comment: Never mind, those features only support Git, answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you are following the instruction for the new CD services that support Git only: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/examples/azure/continuous-to-app-service

If you are still using TFVC you may need to follow the old 2013 instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-continuous-delivery-use-vso

If you want to move to Git to take advantage of this and other features then you can migrate using the Git-TFS tools on GitHub. Or even better, you can start from scratch and ditch binaries...

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I also started to think it only supported Git. I will try some of your suggestions. :-)